# RecyclerView not working within NestedScrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-nestedscrollview

Similar questions for RecyclerView were asked few times in past & I also have tried that solutions to my code but still I'm not able to find actual solution for my issue.
Btw , I'm using UltimateRecyclerView library if that matters to this question.

Here is my code for xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.TestChartActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_scroll_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout_transactions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <info.hoang8f.android.segmented.SegmentedGroup xmlns:segmentedgroup="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/rdGrpChartType"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4"
                segmentedgroup:sc_border_width="2dp"
                segmentedgroup:sc_corner_radius="5dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rdBtn1m"
                    style="@style/RadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="1M" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rdBtn3m"
                    style="@style/RadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="3M" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rdBtn6m"
                    style="@style/RadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="6M" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rdBtn12m"
                    style="@style/RadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="12M" />

            </info.hoang8f.android.segmented.SegmentedGroup>


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_property"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rdGrpChartType"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />


            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart
                android:id="@+id/reports"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_transaction_summary"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_transactions_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/reports">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/transactions_buttons_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/regular_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/transactions_switch_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/transactions_switch_background_border"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radio_transaction_income"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/income_switch_background_selector"
                            android:button="@null"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/title_income"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/income_switch_color_selector" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radio_transaction_expense"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/expense_switch_background_selector"
                            android:button="@null"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                            android:paddingTop="8dp"
                            android:text="@string/title_expense"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/expense_switch_color_selector" />


                    </RadioGroup>
                </LinearLayout>


                <com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/income_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/transactions_buttons_layout"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:recyclerviewClipToPadding="true"
                    app:recyclerviewPadding="2dp" />

                <com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/expense_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/transactions_buttons_layout"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:recyclerviewClipToPadding="true"
                    app:recyclerviewPadding="2dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/no_transaction"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/no_transaction_img"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_no_transaction" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_no_transaction"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/str_no_transaction"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkestGrey"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have attached image of what I achieved so far with above code where RecyclerView stays fixed & scrollable itself but I can't scroll entire list layout.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NestedScrollView and RecyclerView both have a same property which is scroll.

If we add RecyclerView  with in NestedScrollView , then sometime RecyclerView  does not scroll or if scroll it scroll then it scroll seperatly not scroll with nestedscrollview,

If we need scroll whole layout and recyclerview then add the below code in your activity:

```
recyclerviewName.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Using above code recyclerview and scroll together.